# Add <br> tag in place of each line breaks in .ods files

Tags: python, sed

I have a file name sample.ods with more then 9k rows which i need to import in the database.  When i import it in the db it is imported successfully  but the problem is , there is column name description which is in below format :

> description(en)
>
> This is description
>
> Assortment:
>
> - 6 Designs, Fire Engine, Goods Van, Ambulance, Taxi, Police and School Bus
>
> Dimensions (in packaging):
>
> - 9cm x 13cm x 12.5cm
>
> Product dimensions:
>
> - 9.5cm x 8cm x 6.5cm
>
> Weight:
>
> - 0.140kg (including any packaging)

When the file imported in the db, in the website the description comes as

> This is description Assortment: - 6
>   Designs, Fire Engine, Goods Van, Ambulance, Taxi, Police and School
>   Bus Dimensions (in packaging): - 9cm x 13cm x 12.5cm Product
>   dimensions: - 9.5cm x 8cm x 6.5cm Weight: - 0.140kg (including any
>   packaging)

But what i want is

> This is desciption
>
> Assortment: - 6 Designs, Fire Engine, Goods Van, Ambulance, Taxi,
>   Police and School Bus
>
> Dimensions (in packaging): - 9cm x 13cm x 12.5cm
>
> Product dimensions: - 9.5cm x 8cm x 6.5cm Weight: - 0.140kg
>   (including any packaging)

If br tag is added in  place of line breaks it works(get the result as i want), but adding manually in more then 9k rows is not right way.So, how can i add br tag in each row of description column in place of line breaks ?

Any suggestion is appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I do not like much the binary formats, I would first export the ods file in csv format, and try to do the replacement of line breaks with `<br>` tags by reading records from csv, change appropriate colum value and insert in database. But IMHO you should show some code to get a more detailed answer...

Comment: You wrote that this file is sample.ods. Is it plain text file or is it in OpenDocument format as extension suggest?

Comment: @running.t It is OpenDocument fromat as extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to replace the line breaks -- they're getting removed by the import anyway.

You only need to add the `<br>` tags, which is easy with `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/<br>/'
```

An ODS file is a zip archive containing several XML files. I believe it ought to be safe to run the above command on the extracted `content.xml` file. That file does not appear to contain line breaks unless they exist in the data, so a global replace will probably do the right thing.

BTW, since it *is* XML, should you not use `<br/>`?

The whole procedure will look like this:

```
mkdir tmpdir
cd tmpdir
unzip /path/to/file.ods
sed --in-place 's!$!<br/>!' content.xml
zip /path/to/newfile.ods *
```

Comment: This will work as long as this file is a plain text. I know that usually file extension is not enough determine file type, however still it may suggest that in this case file format is in OpenDocument format.

Comment: The ODS file is compressed XML. I presume the OP has managed to remove the compression.

Comment: I've now added the unzip instructions.

Comment: @ams thank you for the solution but when i run the above command , zip the file and try to open the file it doesn't open . Actually, from ods extension i mean OpenDocument format.

Comment: ODS os usually OpenDocument Spreadsheet. It's possible it doesn't open because the `<br/>` at the end of the file is illegal. The question is, does it import into your database correctly? If so, then just modify a copy for import and leave the original alone.

Comment: @Drudge: If this is OpenDocument **Spreadsheet**, you can open the file using LibreOffice, save it as CSV file (but be sure to use **semicolon** as delimier), then use  `sed 's/$/<br>/'` on plaintext CSV file and finaly import result into DB.

Comment: @ams i don't think it will work after importing in db because when i try to cat the file i get some wired character sir .

Comment: @running.t okay i will try it and let you know sir :)

Comment: @running.t Thank you so much sir .. It worked when i change the file to csv format and after running  the sed command :D  No need to unzip the file. Thanks a lot :)